# Why apply an Exponential Moving Average towards 0.0 is slower?

Tags: c++, algorithm, moving-average

This is [my code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4d62c4ff3632e12):

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline void Task(double start, double target) {
    double a0 = 0.0101252;
    double z = start;

    double value = -1.0;
    double temp = 0.0;
    int counter = 0;    
    while (value != temp) {
        temp = value;

        // exponential moving average
        z += a0 * (target - z);
        value = z;

        counter++;
    }

    cout << "start: " << start << " | target: " << target << " | iterations: " << counter << std::endl;    
}

int main() 
{   
    Task(0.0, 0.01);
    Task(0.01, 0.0);

    Task(0.01, 0.02);
    Task(0.02, 0.01);    
}
```

Applying [Exponential Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) from 0.1 to 0.2 (or from 0.2 to 0.1 or 0.0 to 0.1) results in somethings around 3100 iterations:

```
start: 0 | target: 0.01 | iterations: 3173
start: 0.01 | target: 0.02 | iterations: 3105
start: 0.02 | target: 0.01 | iterations: 3173
```

Instead, if I go to 0.0, its somethings like 25 times more expensive in terms of iterations:

```
start: 0.01 | target: 0 | iterations: 72305
```

Why? Where's the tricky part here? I can't figure it out. Denormals?

Comment: in the while loop you never change `target` that you pass to `Process` on each iteration

Comment: @tobi303: of course. its the "target". I don't want to change it!

Comment: but then `Process` will return always the same result... ah wait ... globals... sorry I have to run...

Comment: I place globals for an easy test. Don't mind about them!

Comment: "Don't mind about them! " if I dont mind about them I have no chance to understand the code, that is the problem. .. now i am really gone :P

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @tobi303: edited the code for you!

Comment: @Ron: why it takes 25 times more to go from 0.1 to 0.0 instead of going from 0.0 to 1.0. Its written in the question!

Comment: The trivial answer is: because of your algorithm. Use the debugger to observe the values and see why they differ from the ones you expect.

Comment: this is a maths question rather than coding. Just write down the forumla and it should be obvious. Btw you didnt have to edit anything "for me"

Comment: @tobi303 Not really. The question hinges on the properties of floating-point representation of real numbers; this is in the realm of computer science. In a pure mathematical sense, the formula should work the same for any value of `target`. Also, if we worked with real numbers and not their imperfect approximations, the loop would be infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values representable in a `double` are more dense near zero. You break the loop when `value == temp` - essentially, when you are so close to the target that the error is lost through rounding. This in turn effectively means that you demand much higher precision when `target` is near zero than when `target` has large absolute value.

You probably want to choose a more reasonable precision target than "the very last bit of the mantissa".

Comment: `Values representable in a double are more dense near zero` is due to the denormals? As I stated? Or nothing to do with them?

Comment: @markzzz Denormals make the effect much more pronounced, yes. But even without denormals, the smallest value `e1` such that `1.0 + e1 > 1.0` is much smaller than `e2` such that `1000000.0 + e2 > 1000000.0`.

Comment: How can I learn about this major density near 0? How is called this fp sideeffect?

Comment: I don't know whether this particular phenomenon has a name. As to where to learn more - I'd start with this classic: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)